# jQuery AJAX JSON issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

On the first page I have this function:

```
 <script>
function update() {
  $("#notice_div").html('Loading..'); 


  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: latestid,
    url: '2includejson.php?lastid='+ latestid + '',
    timeout: 4000,
    success: function(data) {


      $("#cont_div").html(data);
      $("#cont_div").clone().prependTo($("#newdiv")); 
      $("#notice_div").html(''); 
      $("#cont_div").html('');
      window.setTimeout(update, 4000);

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#notice_div").html('Timeout contacting server..');
      window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    update();

}); 
</script>
```

And some php.

The included file:

```
    <? 
     header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

    $la = $_GET['lastid'];  
    include ("../../setup.php");

    $jsonArray[] = array();

      $count = 1; // first message is the newest on load
      $get = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM board WHERE id>'$la' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    while ($msg = $DB->fetch_array($get))
    {   

  if($count == 1){ 
  $latestid = $msg['id']; // newest message - this I need to pass to the other page
  }
  $count++; 

    $jsonArray = "$msg[msg]";
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
    ?>
```

I'm just trying to learn how to use ajax and jquery.

As you see, I pass latestid as js variable through the URL
url: '2includejson.php?lastid='+ latestid + '',

I need to renew/post pack a newer value from the included page but I have no idea how to do so. Before using json I could just overwrite it with javascript, but now I don't know... The newer value will then be posted again as latestid.

Comment: `success: function(data) {` <- the id here is in data.id if it was passed from server

Comment: beware of SQL injections here: $la = $_GET['lastid'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the array without `[]`:

```
$jsonArray = array();
```

Also you should then append the data to the array instead of making a string:

```
$jsonArray[] = $msg['msg'];
```

And in the end:

```
$jsonArray['latestid'] = $latestid;
```

Then in JavaScript, you should declare `latestid`:

```
var latestid;
```

And inside the ajax function, you should just pass the data as an object, and not twice like you're doing now. And just replace `latestid` there, which has been returned in JSON format:

```
...
data: {lastid: latestid},
url: '2includejson.php',
timeout: 4000,
success: function(data) {
    latestid = data.latestid; // update latestid
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how to access the passed info in the include file

Comment: @domino: The PHP file? It looks like `$msg` will contain the database values for each record, so if you append those to `$jsonArray` you can pass them to JavaScrpt.

Comment: Yes, but how do I access what used to be "$la = $_GET['lastid'];" in the second file since it's not sent with the URL anymore?

Comment: @domino: It is - anything you pass with `data:` in `jQuery.ajax` will automatically get appended to the URL, as in `{something: 123}` becomes `?something=123`. jQuery will also take care of encoding issues etc.

Comment: Oh I see. That's great. I'm starting to get it. There seems to be one more problem - when updating latestid after success: latestid = data.latestid; it doesn't actually update it for some reason. It is defined at the bottom of the page. Right now it does the first ajax load (with latestid=x), but the next one is without that variable.

Comment: Figured it out, I had to redefine it in the function.

Comment: Yet the value still doesn't update (data: {lastid : latestid}). I am able to grab the new value inside the success function and redefine latestid but it does not update outside the function (last id still sends the old value). Weird.

Comment: @domino: Are you sure you don't use `var` inside the callback? Otherwise you are only defining it inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) {
```

the `data` in here is a json object. so u cant do `$("#cont_div").html(data);` u have to read the json and then write it to a div like this;

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    $("#cont_div").append(key + " "+ value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success: function(data) {


      $("#cont_div").html(data);
      $("#cont_div").clone().prependTo($("#newdiv")); 
      $("#notice_div").html(''); 
      $("#cont_div").html('');
  latestid = data.latestid ; // update the value
      window.setTimeout(update, 4000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the $.parseJSON;

Suppose the server returns a json of the form {"id":"2"}, then in the success function do

```
success:function(data){
var s=$.parseJSON(data);
alert(s.id)-->will alert 2
```

And I'm not sure if your server script returns a properly formated json. Use firebug figure this out